Rider - Cannot invoke (class=MonitoringCppDebugActiveSessionsTrackerListener, method=processStarted, topic=XDebuggerManager events)
Minimal Reproducible Example:

Create a new .NET#8.0 project.
Add the following lines:

Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

Add a breakpoint to the second line.
Run the app with a debugger.
Here is a screenshot:

I'm using:

JetBrains Rider 2024.2
Runtime version: 21.0.3+13-b509.4 amd64 (JCEF 122.1.9)
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
.NET Core v8.0.4 x64 (Server GC)


On the internet, people said to uninstall cucumber+. I do not have this on my computer nor do I have a plugin that has this name.

Look for the plugin "Support for C++ Language" if you see an error about missing dependencies, disable it restart your IDE and enable it again.
This worked for me.

Hi, I can't use it; it says "Not Loaded" and I can't uninstall, load it, re-install it or anything. I'm going to reinstall my computer altogether and see it if works.

Reinstalling the computer altogether worked.
